# How to compile ssh2 on Windows to create a 32bits libssh2.dll

Tags: libssh2, ssh2

I successfully created libssh2.dll on Windows but is 64bits.
How to do the same to producce 32bits libssh2.dll ?

Answer (score 1):

The following compile libssh2 as 32bit dll:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32 -DCRYPTO_BACKEND=WinCNG -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./dll32 --build .
cmake --build . --target install
```